# Angular 2: error when run ng test

Tags: angular

When I run ng test it show error as the following:

> Jquery plugins need to be before this file at localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js

Could you help me to resolve it ? Here is my index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<base href="/">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<title>test</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/css/font.googleapis.com.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/css/font2.googleapis.com.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/plugins/node-waves/waves.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/plugins/animate-css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/css/all-themes.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/print.css" media="print" />
</head>
<body>
<app-root>
<!-- Page Loader -->
<div class="page-loader-wrapper">
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="preloader">
            <div class="spinner-layer pl-red">
                <div class="circle-clipper left">
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="circle-clipper right">
                    <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>Please wait...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- #END# Page Loader -->
</app-root>  
<script src="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/plugins/node-waves/waves.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/plugins/jquery-datatable/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/plugins/jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/js/tables/jquery-datatable.js"></script>
<script src="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/js/admin.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: provide your index.html file and your configurations. As it is, is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I added my index.html file on above.

Answer (score 0):

move this line `<script src="assets/admin_bsb_material_design/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>` and all the others relative to jQuery before `<app-root>`

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I put these into karma.config.js, it run well.
  files: [
  { pattern:'./src/assets/admin_bsb_material_design/plugins/jquery   /jquery.min.js',watched: false }
 .
 .
 .
  { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],